# How to catch tab close event without user interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, onbeforeunload

Basically I'm trying to save some data when a page is closed, even if there's no user interaction. I've tried using the onbeforeunload listener as so:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const requestData = {
    parameter : 'test',
    step: 2
  };

  fetch('/send-data', {
    method : 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({'content-type': 'application/json'}),
    body : JSON.stringify(requestData)
  })
  return undefined;
};
```

I had hoped since i'm not opening a dialog box i'd be able to use the event, but it's only called with user interaction. Is there any way to catch the event (or any other) on tab/window close to send/save some data? Open to using jquery as well.

Comment: Using [navigator.sendBeacon()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) in modern browsers is far more reliable than using unload events

Comment: this works coupled with visibilitychange, thanks!